# How to prove that $f_{2k}+f_{2k-1}$ is a divisor of $xf_{4k}-2f_{4k-1}-2$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, recurrence-relations

Let $f_i$ are polynomials (of degree $i$) in variable $x$ which satisfies the following recurrence relation:
$$f_{k+1}=xf_k-f_{k-1}\text{ for }k\ge1, \text{ and }$$ $$f_0=1, f_1=x.$$
How to prove that $f_{2k}+f_{2k-1}$ is a divisor of $xf_{4k}-2f_{4k-1}-2?$

Comment: Did you try induction? It always works in these cases.

Comment: Here I don't what $f_k$ exactly is. So how to apply induction.

Comment: Can't be right.  The recurrence is homogeneous in $f$, and so is $f_{2k}+f_{2k+1}$, but $x f_{4k} - 2 f_{4k-1} - 2$ is not.  I suspect there's something missing from the last term.

Comment: Seems to be $f_{2k} + f_{2k+1}$ is a divisor of $x f_{4k} - 2 f_{4k-1} + f_0 - f_2$.

Comment: Can we express the polynomials as linear combination of power of matrices similar to how it is done when the recurrence is purely over $Z$?

Comment: I obtain a series $f_1 = ax-b, f_2 = ax^2-bx-a, f_3 = ax^3-bx^2-2ax+b, \ldots$ but I don't obtain the desired result? Is something wrong?

Comment: @RobertIsrael You are right. I had a typo error. Actually $\bf{f_{2k}+f_{2k-1}}$ is a divisor.

Comment: It's still wrong.

Comment: Unless you specify initial conditions $f_0 = 1$, $f_1 = x$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Now can you please help me towards proving this question.